# Purpose of .push_deviceid file

Tags: privacy, files

On some Android devices, in the `data` folder (within user storage), there is a file called `.push_deviceid`

For example, on one Android device, I found it at `storage/emulated/0/data/.push_deviceid`

It is a text file that contains a 32-byte hexadecimal value.

Searching the internet has not resulted in helpful results.

Does anyone know the purpose of this file, or what created it?

If not, besides deleting it (or renaming it) and then running every app to see what recreates it, is there a way to find what process created the file?

Comment: @Firelord My initial choice of words were not ideal and were not clear.  Thank you for noticing and pointing it out.  I've updated the text to be more clear.  AFAIK, it's not a default Android file, but a file that is created/used by some apps or common libraries.  I would like to know which ones, and what purpose it serves.

Comment: I searched my three devices running Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2, and 5.0.2. Nowhere I can see this file. I guess it's either device specific (which device are you using) or app specific?

Comment: I'm guessing it's created by one or more apps or common libraries, as it's on devices from several different manufacturers.